# What is wrong with Bootstrap 3 RC2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just downloaded latest version of Bootstrap and the code I have written looking at the example file is not working at all. Please help me to find out if I am doing anything wrong or Bootstrap has uploaded bullshit files on the net.

The code below does not showing navigation bar. I found out that collapse class is given display: none; and when I resize browser the navigation is appearing with click on button but it is so ugly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Static Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->

</head>

<body>

<!-- Static navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="/examples/navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="/examples/navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li><a href="/examples/navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="../../docs/#navbar">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what is and isn't working? Does the code you've written work with other versions of bootstrap?

Comment: RC2 is new (today), and the examples are not yet up to date. 'navbar-header' and 'navbar-collapse' are now used.. http://bootply.com/74266

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you [check the release notes for RC2](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/13/bootstrap-3-rc2/):

> - Navbar:
>
>   - Overhauled navbar to always be responsive and mobile first.
>     **Navbars now require a .navbar-header** to wrap up brand and toggle.
>   - **.nav-collapse has been renamed to .navbar-collapse** and automatically hits a max-height and will overflow to keep your nav content in the same viewport.
>     See details in #9403.
>   - Navbar's **no longer use .pull-left or .pull-right, but rather .navbar-left and .navbar-right.** This avoids issues with specificity due to chaining classes and enables easier styling.

Comment: Yeah that is true. But I expected the examples provided on the website to follow these rules.